# how to play two AVAudioPlayer using singleton object...?

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am beginner of iPhone. I want to play two sound one by one. one stop and then second play.only one button click event play two sound one by one and using singleton object. give any source code and suggestion which apply in my apps...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delegate method

`- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag`, which belongs to the protocol `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`.

You can read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying%3asuccessfully%3a).